# devenv.com is running from the cmd but unable to run it from jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, installation

I want to build the Setup.vdproj file from the Jenkins. It is successfully run from cmd promt.

**COMMMAND is** :

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "D:\Project\Test\WPF\WpfApp_TestProj\WpfApp_TestProj.sln" /Rebuild Release /Project "D:\Project\Test\WPF\WpfApp_TestProj\SetupProj\SetupProj.vdproj" /projectconfig Release

But when it's run from the Jenkins it shown-

**The license for Visual Studio has expired.**

Note: Both Visual Studio & Jenkins User ID is same. **Found that in cmd 'whoami' = 'crp abc' but in jenkins batch command 'whoami' = 'nt authority\system'**
But Jenkins Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace D:\Project\Test\WPF\WPF Test

Please help to solve.

Comment: From the error message, looks like the error is caused by the expired Visual Studio license. Have you tried to [sign in VS Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/community-edition-expired-buy-license/)?

Comment: yes, signed in visual studio and updated the community licnse. Not working.

Comment: Now geting another error:

Comment: ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'

...
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

After googling exuting windows bat comment from Jenkins before the devenv.com build setup project. 
CD: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild\
CALL: DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe

not working.